# How do I use more than nine backreferences in Notepad++ regexp?

Tags: regex, notepad++, backreference, capturing-group

If I use a long regular expression in Notepad++, i.e.:

```
^([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) (\[.*?\]) (".*?") (".*?") (".*?") (".*?") (\d+) (\d+) (\d+)$
```

*(this is for turning an Apache log lines from space-separated to tab-separated)*

then I can't successfully use more than nine backreferences for replacing, as `\10` yields the content of the first captured group plus a literal "0".

I tried with `$10`, but that gives the same result.

Comment: use curly brackets: `${10}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use curly braces for this:

```
${10}
```

For reference, Notepad++ uses `boost::regex`, and you can find its substitution pattern docs here: [Boost-Extended Format String Syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html). This replacement mode allows for more complex expressions (like conditionals and common Perl placeholders) in the replacement pattern.

Comment: Does this means I can use it the same for javascript regexp?

Comment: @Rahul: No, JS "understands" `$10` (it is rather smart in disambiguating backreference IDs).

Comment: @Rahul JavaScript has its own regex spec, but in JS you can simply use a callback function for replacements, so the problem is non-existent.

Comment: Thanks for the additional documentation!

Answer (score 2):

Just use the curly braces:

`${10}`

This will ensure that the 10th capturing group is being referred, and not the 1st group followed by zero.